# Fill ListBox with checkbox in MVC using Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to fill the values in `Listbox` with checkbox control using `ajax` call.

But unable to fill the data in listbox.

In View:

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { id = "cmbCity", @style = "width: 100px;" })

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cmbCity').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true     
    });

    $('#btnShowCity').on('click', function () {    
        $.ajax({
            url: '../CN/Get_City',
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',               
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#cmbCity").html("");
                $.each($.parseJSON(data.result_City), function (i, city) {
                    $("#cmbCity").append
                        ($('<option>                                   </option>').val(city.ID).html(city.Name))
               })  
              $('#cmbCity').multiselect('refresh');
            }
        })
});
```

**In Controller:**

[HttpPost]

```
public string Get_City()
{
    clsDAL objclDAL = new clsDAL();

    DataTable _resultDataset =FillDataTable("SELECT [ID], Name FROM City");      
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result_City = _resultDataset });
}
```

Kindly give me some suggestion

Comment: You appear to be using a jQuery plugin for the listbox, so you would need to call its method to refresh the data (just start by commenting out your `$('#cmbCity').multiselect({ ... })` code to ensure the options are loading (your controller code makes no sense - we do not even know what `result_City` is or what properties it contains)

Comment: Hi Stephen, i have edited the code of controller

Comment: Still makes no sense - it does not even compile! What is the `var jsonData ...` line of code for - you never use `jsonData`. And the `return ...` line of code refere to `result_City` which does not even exist

Comment: Sorry Stephen, This is mistake from my side. But my problem is in View.  i dont undestand how to fill the options

Comment: Why in the world are you serializing it twice?

Comment: And read the first comment!

Comment: Hi stephen, first of all thanx for your serialization comments. I am unnecessary adding the seriaization in the code . Data is filling in listbox but list is not populated . When i select the "select all" checkbox , it shows the count of records in the list box. i dont understand where i am wrong

Comment: Again, read my first comment - you using a plugin - you need to call its `refresh` method after you add the options

Comment: added the code to refresh. $('#cmbCity').multiselect('refresh'); But list popup is not coming but there is data in list

Comment: That code is executed before the ajax (ajax is async)

Comment: Added async : false but still issue is same

Comment: You need to do it in the success callback. And NEVER use `async : false`!

Comment: Thanx. but the refresh code is already written in success callback

Comment: Just how many time are you going to keep completely changing your question!!!

Comment: I am changing the code only for reference that what changes i have made in my code

Comment: My issue has been resolved just replace the "refresh" with "rebuild"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each($.parseJSON(data.result_City), function (i, city) {
          $("#City").append($('<option></option>').val(city.ID).html(city.Name))
});

//--------mvc code block
//@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { @style = "width: 100px;" })
//delete  id = "cmbCity" because your id ="Name" and name="Name"
```

Comment: I have already changed in the code. data is filling in Listbox but unable to get the list.  When i am selection the select all , it shows the count of records in the listbox